# How to show that $\cos(3n)$ has alternating sign?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, trigonometry

Suppose $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then show that $\cos(3n)$ has alternating sign.

I know that $n \mod 2\pi$ has four outcomes:

- $n \mod 2\pi \in [0,\frac{2}{\pi}]$ then $\cos(n) >=0$
- $n \mod 2\pi \in [3\frac{\pi}{2},2\pi]$ then $\cos(n) >=0$
- $n \mod 2\pi \in ]\frac{\pi}{2},\pi[$ then $\cos(n)<0$
- $n \mod 2\pi \in ]\pi,3\frac{2}{\pi}[$ then $\cos(n)<0$

But how should I should that each time we increment $n$, the $n \mod 2\pi$ jumps into a different group of intervals( the two groups of intervals being the one where $\cos$ is positive and $\cos$ is negative)?

Comment: Could be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem Notice also that the sign are not strictly speaking *"alternating"* as for instance $\cos 33$ and $\cos 36$ are both negative.

Comment: Yeah, might be better to ask that $\cos(3n)$ changes sign infinitely often

Comment: This question is broken! By the usual interpretation, $\cos 3n$ does _not_ have alternating sign: $\cos 3n$ and $\cos 3(n+1)$ do not in general have different signs.

Comment: @SimpleArt I am studying a simple alternating series, but if $cos(3n)$ isn't alternating, then there is no point in proving that it changes the sign infinitely many times.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thank you for the article! And also for the counter-example!

Comment: LaTeX hint: use `\cos` and `\mod`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can say is that
$$
\cos(3n)=\cos((3-\pi)n+\pi n)=(-1)^n\cos\cos((\pi-3)n)
$$
The second factor is slow moving, but does not have a constant sign. Indeed, around
$$
n=\left\lfloor\frac{\pi (k+\frac12)}{\pi-3}\right\rfloor
$$
you will see a sign change in the second factor and thus a constant sign from $\cos(3n)$ to $\cos(3(n+1))$.

First values are

```
k   n   cos(3*(n-1)) cos(3*n)  cos(3*(n+1)) cos(3*(n+2))
--------------------------------------------------------
 0  11  0.15425145 -0.01327675 -0.12796369  0.26664293
 1  33 -0.18043045  0.03982088  0.1015857  -0.24095905
 2  55  0.20648223 -0.06633694 -0.07513609  0.21510527
 3  77 -0.23238842  0.09280622  0.0486335  -0.18909982
 4  99  0.25813076 -0.11921006 -0.02209662  0.16296104
 5 122  0.14552986 -0.00445584 -0.13670736  0.27513436
 6 144 -0.17174704  0.03100516  0.11035728 -0.24951093
 7 166  0.19784312 -0.05753262 -0.0839294   0.22371157
 8 188 -0.22379971  0.08401951  0.05744234 -0.19775448
 9 210  0.2495985  -0.11044716 -0.03091477  0.17165795
10 232 -0.2752213   0.13679694  0.00436541 -0.14544039
11 255 -0.16305026  0.02218703  0.11912028 -0.25804339
12 277  0.18918862 -0.04872383 -0.09271618  0.23230046
13 299 -0.21519358  0.07522627  0.0662467  -0.20639374
14 321  0.24104682 -0.10167567 -0.03973052  0.1803415
15 343 -0.26673009  0.12805338  0.01318632 -0.1541621
16 366 -0.1543408   0.01336717  0.127874   -0.26655577
17 388  0.1805194  -0.03991124 -0.10149574  0.24087128
18 410 -0.20657071  0.06642717  0.07504591 -0.21501695
19 432  0.23247638 -0.09289626 -0.04854317  0.18901102
20 454 -0.25821813  0.11929985  0.02200621 -0.16287181
```